# Using config module in NodeJs returning 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, configuration-files

I was trying to run the sample here.  He didn't show how he stored his config values.  Based on the doc https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config, I did the following:

```
npm install config 
npm config set database Demo1 
npm config list
```

The list showed the variable set. But in node, I tried this:

```
var config = require("config") ;
console.log("config.database=" + config.database);
```

Which shows the output:

> config.database=undefined

Part 2 - would this config module work well in an AWS Lambda environment as well?  I'm testing on Windows right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now.  I didn't catch the difference between 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config
and 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config.

With the second one, I created in my project folder a config directory and within that a file called default.json, and put the text below in that file.

```
{
  "database": "MyDBName"
}
```

Obviously, I'll add the other parms, but just wanted to see it work with one parm first.

I can see this being compatible with AWS Lambda since it is just a JSON file. And has further capabiltiies of nested names/values, arrays, etc...